# Would it be better to watch the live action movie or the anime series to experience the original manga?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

I was wondering if I  wanted to experience Fullmetal Alchemist where should I start; should I watch the live-action movie in one go or start the anime series on the long road.
I'm not sure if it will be a waste to watch either one of them before the other.
And the movie is easy to get too!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you're picking between the anime or the live action, the anime is probably your best bet, specifically Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood as it is the closest adaptation of the original manga.

Comment: Thank you i guess you're right,  and now got to find a good site to watch it. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, since this is a Q&A site, you might want to rephrase your question to be less opinion-based and more like "Would it be better to watch the live action movie or the anime series to experience the story of the original manga?"

Comment: @user38436 reminder that pirating animes or related is unethical and doesn't support the industry.

Comment: I believe Netflix also has Brotherhood on top of the live action movie

Comment: @Cyberson yea it sounds more like a guessing game!thanks

Comment: @Cyberson thanks a lot again!  I hope you have a great day Im fired up to know the story 